# Codenameone: how to check internet connection and suspended mode

Tags: codenameone

We want to check Internet connection on the initial state and want to handle exception for that and want to show a pop-up message.

We want to get suspended mode state of form when we minimize it. Can you please let me know how to resolve it?

My application needs to be supported on all platforms (Android, iOS, Windows) and I don't want to write native code for all platforms separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this 3rd party lib: https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/codenameone-connectivity

Comment: You can detect app minimization (suspend) via the `stop()` method callback and the `isMinimized()` method of `Display` that can be simulated using the "suspend/resume" feature in the simulator. Notice that Chens link above can be installed via our new extension manager: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/automatically-install-update-distribute-cn1libs-extensions.html

Comment: can you give sample code for checking connectivity.how can i check connectivity using lib ?

Comment: There is a usage entry within the link above